# No endpoint mapping found for SaajSoapMessage

Tags: spring, soap

I have been having issues trying to get endpoint mapping to work for my web service. I am using Tomcat to host my web service and I am using soapUI to send test messages to it.

The following message from the Tomcat log shows the creation of the endpoint mapping bean:

```
6458 [http-apr-8080-exec-6] DEBUG org.springframework.ws.soap.server.endpoint.mapping.SoapActionEndpointMapping  - Mapped key [{http://endpoint.ws.example.com}pushAbcToXyzOperation] onto endpoint [com.abc.xc.model.PushAbcToXyzRequest@131ebb3[...]]
```

However, the endpoint mapping bean must be incorrect because I receive the following "no endpoint mapping found" message:

```
6739 [http-apr-8080-exec-6] WARN  org.springframework.ws.server.EndpointNotFound  - No endpoint mapping found for [SaajSoapMessage {http://endpoint.ws.example.com}pushAbcToXyzOperation]
```

Here is the web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
         version="2.4">

    <display-name>abc2xyzWS</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring-ws</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>WEB-INF/spring-ws-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring-ws</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Here is the spring-ws-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:sws="http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services/web-services-2.0.xsd">

    <sws:annotation-driven/>
    <context:annotation-config />

    <import resource="classpath:/xyz-endpoint-context.xml" />

    <!--==========================================================
    *
    *  Spring Web Service Configuration
    *
    =============================================================-->

    <bean name="loadPayload" class="org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.mapping.PayloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping">
        <description>
            Detects @PayloadRoot annotations on @Endpoint bean methods.
        </description>

        <property name="interceptors">
            <list>
                <bean class="org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.interceptor.PayloadLoggingInterceptor"/>
                <bean class="org.springframework.ws.soap.server.endpoint.interceptor.PayloadValidatingInterceptor">
                    <property name="schema" value="classpath:/AbcAPI.xsd"/>
                    <property name="validateRequest" value="true"/>
                    <property name="validateResponse" value="true"/>
                </bean>
            </list>
        </property>

        <property name="order" value="1"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="pushService" class="com.abc.xc.model.PushAbcToXyzRequest"/>

    <bean id="endpointMapping" class="org.springframework.ws.soap.server.endpoint.mapping.SoapActionEndpointMapping">
       <property name="mappings">
          <props>
              <prop key="{http://endpoint.ws.example.com}pushAbcToXyzOperation">pushService</prop>
          </props>
       </property>

    </bean>

</beans>
```

Here is the xyz-endpoint-context.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <import resource="classpath:/applicationContext.xml" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.abc.ws.endpoint"/>
</beans>
```

Here is the applicationContext.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"

       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd">

    <!--===========================================================================
     *
     *  opis2pips service module configuration.
     *
     =============================================================================-->
     <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:/applicationContext.properties"/>
     <context:component-scan base-package="com.abc.xc.service"/>

     <bean id="serviceURL" class="java.lang.String">
         <constructor-arg><value>${serviceURL}</value></constructor-arg>
     </bean>
     ...
     <bean id="emailerrormessage" class="java.lang.String">
        <constructor-arg><value>${emailerrormessage}</value></constructor-arg>
     </bean> 

</beans>
```

Here is the endpoint

```
package com.abc.ws.endpoint.endpoint;

import com.abc.xc.model.WSstatusType;
import com.abc.xc.model.PushAbcToXyzRequest;
import com.abc.xc.model.QueryXyzRequest;
import com.abc.xc.model.XyzResponse;
import com.abc.xc.service.XyzClient;
import com.abc.xc.service.WSemailService;
import com.abc.xc.service.AbcToXyzTranslationService;
import com.abc.xc.exception.WSexception;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.annotation.Endpoint;
import org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.annotation.PayloadRoot;
import org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.annotation.RequestPayload;
import org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.annotation.ResponsePayload;

import contracts.xyz.GetTicketResponse;
import contracts.xyz.PostTicketResponse;
import contracts.xyz.Ticket;
import contracts.xyz.TicketMessageProcessingResult;

@Endpoint
public class XyzWebServiceController {
    @Autowired
    private XyzClient XyzClientservice;
    @Autowired
    private AbcToXyzTranslationService translationservice;
    @Autowired
    WSemailService mailservice;

    protected static final String NAMESPACE_URI = "http://www.example.com/schema";

    @PayloadRoot(namespace = NAMESPACE_URI, localPart = "PushAbcToXyzRequest")

    @ResponsePayload
    public XyzResponse PushAbcToXyzOperation(@RequestPayload PushAbcToXyzRequest PushAbcToXyzRequest){

        XyzResponse XyzResponse = null;
        Ticket ticket = null;
        try {
            ticket = translationservice.abcInputToXyzTicket(PushAbcToXyzRequest);
            PostTicketResponse response = XyzClientservice.postTicket(ticket);
            Long transactionid = response.getInteractionId();

            if(transactionid != null){
                GetTicketResponse gtresponse = XyzClientservice.getTicket();
                Ticket gtresponseTicket = gtresponse.getTicket().getValue();
                XyzResponse =  translationservice.XyzTicketToXyzResponse(gtresponseTicket);
            }

            XyzResponse.setWSstatus(WSstatusType.SUCCESS);
            mailservice.sendEmail(true, PushAbcToXyzRequest, transactionid);
...
```

Here is the SOAP request

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:end="http://endpoint.ws.example.com" xmlns:mod="http://model.xc.example.com">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <end:pushAbcToXyzOperation>
         <end:pushAbcToXyzRequest>
            ...
         </end:pushAbcToXyzRequest>
      </end:pushAbcToXyzOperation>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Here is a portion of the Tomcat log, from the creation of the endpoint mapping bean, through the "no endpoint mapping found" message:

```
6349 [http-apr-8080-exec-6] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory  - Finished creating instance of bean 'loadPayload'
6349 [http-apr-8080-exec-6] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory  - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'pushService'
6349 [http-apr-8080-exec-6] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory  - Creating instance of bean 'pushService'
6365 [http-apr-8080-exec-6] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory  - Eagerly caching bean 'pushService' to allow for resolving potential circular references
6427 [http-apr-8080-exec-6] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory  - Finished creating instance of bean 'pushService'
6427 [http-apr-8080-exec-6] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory  - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'endpointMapping'
6427 [http-apr-8080-exec-6] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory  - Creating instance of bean 'endpointMapping'
6427 [http-apr-8080-exec-6] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory  - Eagerly caching bean 'endpointMapping' to allow for resolving potential circular references
6443 [http-apr-8080-exec-6] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory  - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'pushService'
6458 [http-apr-8080-exec-6] DEBUG org.springframework.ws.soap.server.endpoint.mapping.SoapActionEndpointMapping  - Mapped key [{http://endpoint.ws.example.com}pushAbcToXyzOperation] onto endpoint [com.abc.xc.model.PushAbcToXyzRequest@131ebb3[requestID=<null>, ...]]
6458 [http-apr-8080-exec-6] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory  - Finished creating instance of bean 'endpointMapping'
6458 [http-apr-8080-exec-6] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory  - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor$ImportAwareBeanPostProcessor#0'
6474 [http-apr-8080-exec-6] DEBUG org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext  - Unable to locate LifecycleProcessor with name 'lifecycleProcessor': using default [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor@13a0067]
6474 [http-apr-8080-exec-6] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory  - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'lifecycleProcessor'
6505 [http-apr-8080-exec-6] INFO  org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory  - Creating SAAJ 1.3 MessageFactory with SOAP 1.1 Protocol
6505 [http-apr-8080-exec-6] DEBUG org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory  - Using MessageFactory class [com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_1.SOAPMessageFactory1_1Impl]
6505 [http-apr-8080-exec-6] DEBUG org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet  - No WebServiceMessageFactory found in servlet 'spring-ws': using default
6505 [http-apr-8080-exec-6] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory  - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.DefaultMethodEndpointAdapter#0'
6521 [http-apr-8080-exec-6] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory  - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.ws.soap.server.endpoint.SoapFaultAnnotationExceptionResolver#0'
6521 [http-apr-8080-exec-6] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory  - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.ws.soap.server.endpoint.SimpleSoapExceptionResolver#0'
6521 [http-apr-8080-exec-6] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory  - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.mapping.PayloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping#0'
6521 [http-apr-8080-exec-6] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory  - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.ws.soap.server.endpoint.mapping.SoapActionAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping#0'
6521 [http-apr-8080-exec-6] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory  - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.ws.soap.addressing.server.AnnotationActionEndpointMapping#0'
6521 [http-apr-8080-exec-6] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory  - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'loadPayload'
6521 [http-apr-8080-exec-6] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory  - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'endpointMapping'
6521 [http-apr-8080-exec-6] DEBUG org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet  - No MessageDispatcher found in servlet 'spring-ws': using default
6521 [http-apr-8080-exec-6] DEBUG org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet  - Published WebApplicationContext of servlet 'spring-ws' as ServletContext attribute with name [org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.CONTEXT.spring-ws]
6521 [http-apr-8080-exec-6] INFO  org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet  - FrameworkServlet 'spring-ws': initialization completed in 6053 ms
6521 [http-apr-8080-exec-6] DEBUG org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet  - Servlet 'spring-ws' configured successfully
6583 [http-apr-8080-exec-6] DEBUG org.springframework.ws.transport.http.WebServiceMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter  - Accepting incoming [org.springframework.ws.transport.http.HttpServletConnection@7ac6c] at [http://localhost:8080/abc2xyzWS/services/XyzWebServiceController]
6677 [http-apr-8080-exec-6] DEBUG org.springframework.ws.server.MessageTracing.received  - Received request [SaajSoapMessage {http://endpoint.ws.example.com}pushAbcToXyzOperation]
6723 [http-apr-8080-exec-6] DEBUG org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.mapping.PayloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping  - Looking up endpoint for [{http://endpoint.ws.example.com}pushAbcToXyzOperation]
6723 [http-apr-8080-exec-6] DEBUG org.springframework.ws.soap.server.SoapMessageDispatcher  - Endpoint mapping [org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.mapping.PayloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping@14481bb] has no mapping for request
6723 [http-apr-8080-exec-6] DEBUG org.springframework.ws.soap.server.endpoint.mapping.SoapActionAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping  - Looking up endpoint for []
6723 [http-apr-8080-exec-6] DEBUG org.springframework.ws.soap.server.SoapMessageDispatcher  - Endpoint mapping [org.springframework.ws.soap.server.endpoint.mapping.SoapActionAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping@a14fed] has no mapping for request
6723 [http-apr-8080-exec-6] DEBUG org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.mapping.PayloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping  - Looking up endpoint for [{http://endpoint.ws.example.com}pushAbcToXyzOperation]
6723 [http-apr-8080-exec-6] DEBUG org.springframework.ws.soap.server.SoapMessageDispatcher  - Endpoint mapping [org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.mapping.PayloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping@868c6d] has no mapping for request
6723 [http-apr-8080-exec-6] DEBUG org.springframework.ws.soap.server.SoapMessageDispatcher  - Endpoint mapping [org.springframework.ws.soap.addressing.server.AnnotationActionEndpointMapping@45484a] has no mapping for request
6723 [http-apr-8080-exec-6] DEBUG org.springframework.ws.soap.server.SoapMessageDispatcher  - Endpoint mapping [org.springframework.ws.soap.server.endpoint.mapping.SoapActionEndpointMapping@8d00c6] has no mapping for request
6739 [http-apr-8080-exec-6] WARN  org.springframework.ws.server.EndpointNotFound  - No endpoint mapping found for [SaajSoapMessage {http://endpoint.ws.example.com}pushAbcToXyzOperation]
```

Please let me know if you need to see any additional information, and thank you in advance for any help in solving this issue.

Answer (score 2):

We faced a similar problem and in our case was that the EndPoint was not included in the component scan directive on the spring configuration.

In the configuration you indicated you are using:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.abc.ws.endpoint"/>
```

But your endpoint is in the next package:

```
package com.abc.ws.endpoint.endpoint;
```

So you have to change the component-scan tag, something like:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.abc.ws.endpoint.endpoint"/>
```

Or refactor the endpoint to another package.

Comment: Where do I put this line, in which file?

Comment: In a configuration file loaded by spring during the initialization if you are using xml configuration instead of annotations

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't the NAMESPACE_URI value be the same as the namespace specified in the wsdl and the xml endpointMapping in spring-ws-context.xml? The namespace specified in NAMESPACE_URI does not include ".ws", which is included in the wsdl namespace and the endpointMapping configuration.

To help with troubleshooting this issue and as a regression test in the future, you might want to write an "endpoint integration test" that you can run from Eclipse and as part of your build process (http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/site/reference/html/server.html#d5e1526).

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you have multiple ApplicationContexts (multiple xml-s containing bean definitions) and **PayloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping** by default only looks for endpoints in its own ApplicationContext (in its own xml). To force the detection of endpoints in other xml-s, you have to set the **detectEndpointsInAncestorContexts** property of **PayloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping** to **true**.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I just add into context tag packages with endpoint class and implementation class like:

```
 <context:component-scan base-package="com.abc.ws.services ,com.abc.ws.endpoint"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was following [Spring's guide on creating a SOAP web service using Springboot](https://spring.io/guides/gs/producing-web-service/) and got the same error. I'm unsure what caused it, but I found that when I tried to make a request like this using WebServiceTemplate in my integration test, I got the 404, even though during my test execution the server was up and the WSDL was available. This is what I did when it didn't work:

```
    final String request = "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\"\n" +
            "\t\t\t\t  xmlns:gs=\"http://spring.io/guides/gs-producing-web-service\">\n" +
            "   <soapenv:Header/>\n" +
            "   <soapenv:Body>\n" +
            "      <gs:getCountryRequest>\n" +
            "         <gs:name>Spain</gs:name>\n" +
            "      </gs:getCountryRequest>\n" +
            "   </soapenv:Body>\n" +
            "</soapenv:Envelope>";

    StreamSource source = new StreamSource(new StringReader(request));
    StreamResult result = new StreamResult(System.out);

    webServiceTemplate.sendSourceAndReceiveToResult("http://localhost:8080/ws", source, result);
```

When I changed this to use the marshaller instead of the raw request string like this:

```
        Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
    marshaller.setContextPath("io.spring.guides.gs_producing_web_service");
    marshaller.setSchema(new ClassPathResource("countries.xsd"));
    webServiceTemplate.setMarshaller(marshaller);
    webServiceTemplate.setUnmarshaller(marshaller);

    GetCountryRequest getCountryRequest = new GetCountryRequest();
    getCountryRequest.setName("Spain");
    GetCountryResponse getCountryResponse = (GetCountryResponse) webServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive("http://localhost:" + serverPort + "/ws", getCountryRequest);

    assertThat(getCountryResponse.getCountry().getName()).isEqualTo("Spain");
    assertThat(getCountryResponse.getCountry().getCapital()).isEqualTo("Madrid");
    assertThat(getCountryResponse.getCountry().getCurrency()).isEqualTo(Currency.EUR);
    assertThat(getCountryResponse.getCountry().getPopulation()).isEqualTo(46704314);
```

where I actually used the generated WSDL classes, then the same request was successful. I have a feeling the original raw request string was incompatible, even though I could use that exact same string via a curl request to my SOAP endpoint and that works (like it tells you to do in the guide).

Answer (score 0):

rename the class `XyzWebServiceController` to `XyzWebServiceControllerEndpoint`